# if statement based on date()

Tags: php, mysql

OK, I am new to PHP coding and I tried to look over previous questions here so if I missed something, please let me know.

Using a PHP if statement, I am trying to have one known working PHP/MySQL codeset run between the hours of 11pm to 8am and another known working PHP/MySQL codeset the rest of the day.

Please let me know if you need any further elaboration to understand my question and thank you for the assistance!

```
<?php
if (date('H')>=23 || date('H')<=08)      {

   Runs a PHP/MySQL query that is know to work. The IF statement never runs this code.

}
else
 {

   Runs another PHP/MySQL query that is know to work. The IF statement always returns FALSE and runs this code.

}
?>
```

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: Sorry, I mention in the code that the IF statement always returns false. I'm trying to find out why.

Comment: `08` is a number in octal representation, and since octal number can only have digits 0 to 7, it is invalid. Maybe that is the cause?

Answer (score 0):

```
date('H')<=08
```

A `number` (not a `quoted string`) with a leading zero is treated as an octal value.... `08` is invalid as an octal value, and is treated as a numeric zero, so `date('H')<=08` equivalent to `date('H')<=0`

**EDIT**

Either allow PHP's loose typing to convert your Hour string to an integer:

```
date('H')<=8
```

or use loose type comparison for both sides of the comparison (with `08` as a quoted string, which will loose cast to decimal `8`):

```
date('H')<='08'
```

or use date format mask `'G'`

```
date('G')<=8
```

Comment: Thanks. OK, so since date('H') returns the hour in 00-23 military format, how do I refer to it? Should I use date('G') instead?

Comment: OK I just tried an experiment and --  if (date('H')>=13 || date('H')<=14) -- still came up as false with the else statement working perfectly. I had the server echo date('H') and it was successful and correct. Any ideas?

Comment: `if (date('H')>=13 || date('H')<=14)` should always come up `true` (not `false`) because every hour of the day is either >= 13 or <= 14.... 01:00 would be true because it's <= 14; 23:00 would be true because it's >= 13.... so it doesn't matter what the value of date('H') is in that new expression.... if you're getting a false from `if (date('H')>=13 || date('H')<=14)` then you have a much more serious underlying problem.... perhaps you meant `if (date('H')>=13 && date('H')<=14)`, which will be true only between `13:00:00.00` and `14:00:00.00`

Comment: I know! That is why I am stumped. That is the whole statement copied straight from my code. Is there another way I can approach the IF statement?

Comment: Then you've found some unique bug in PHP's comparison logic or loose type casting that nobody else in the world has ever encountered before.... and I'm afraid I can't help you with that other than to suggest that you create a [simple self-contained example](http://sscce.org/) to demonstrate this bug, and post it to bugs.php.net

Comment: Sadly, no version of PHP confirms this as a bug: [3v4l.org](http://3v4l.org/G6Nfu) returns  a `true` for all versions of PHP since 4.3.0.... no version gives a `false`